# Why does my method not build a proper XML query from user input?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to take user input from a text box and build an XML query with it.

The query should search within the document for an element with a given attribute 'dataItemId' and return the `innerText` value. 
The two lines of code which are commented out within the `try{}` statement work as expected, returning the correct value, yet when I try to use the two lines above these and type 'Xabs' into my input box I am getting:

> Your resultant Query XPath: //*[dataItemId = 'Xabs'] 
>   No Items Found."

It must be something to do with how the string is parsed but I'm stumped as to what.

```
public void MazakButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userInput = searchInput.Text;
        ResultBox.Items.Clear();
        string query = "No Query Found";
        string searchResult = "No Items Found";

        if (userInput.Length > 3)// If query paramater is long enough
        {                
            //string Query = "\"//*[dataItemId = '" + userInput + "']\""; // Build Attribite Query
                query = "//*[dataItemId = '" + userInput + "']"; // Build Attribite Query
            XmlDocument MTData = MTFunctions.ScrapeXMLData(MazakSourceURL, false);

            try
            {
                XmlNode target = MTData.SelectSingleNode(query);
                searchResult = userInput + ": " + target.InnerText;
                //XmlNode target = MTData.SelectSingleNode("//*[@dataItemId = 'Xabs']"); 
                //searchResult = target.InnerText;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! - XML SEARCH FAILED - !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
        else{searchResult = "Invalid request (Too short)";}


        searchInput.Focus();
        ResultBox.Items.Add("Your Resultant Query XPath: " + query);
        ResultBox.Items.Add(searchResult);
        searchInput.Text = string.Empty; // Clear searchInput 
    }
```

Comment: Two queries are different, you use "[dataItemId" in the first one and "[@dataItemId" in the second one. See the "@" before "dataItemId"

Comment: @NthDeveloper well spotted! :')

Answer (score 0):

First point: you should never build a query by string concatenation incorporating user input. Google "SQL injection attacks" to find out why (most of the literature is in SQL terms, but XPath has exactly the same vulnerabilities).

If you use an expression with a variable, like `//*[dataItemId = $userInput]` then (a) you are protected against injection attacks, (b) you don't need to worry about escaping special characters in the input (like apostrophes), and (c) it's much more efficient because you only need to compile the XPath expression once.

The only difficulty is that you need to work out how to supply a parameter to the query (that is, a value for `$userInput`) before executing it. That depends on the API to your XPath processor and I'm not familiar with the XPath processor that you are using, so you'll need to research this yourself.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the security risks, however, this is just a little application I am writing to familiarise myself with c# and won't ever be in the hands of anyone else or web facing so I'm not too worried about that here. Good to keep in mind though.

Comment: Even without the security risks, it's easier to write the code using a variable rather than using string concatenation.

Comment: In this case there is controlled language for the terms that are being searched, so perhaps something like a closest match lookup table which returns the actual text to be passed to the query construction would work? 
This way I could ensure that only a list of pre-approved strings is used to build queries since there is such a limited selection of searches the user needs to do?

Comment: In that case the benefits of compiling a parameterized query once and executing it repeatedly are even greater. Remember that compiling the query can cost 100 times as much as executing it. I'm not sure why you are so resistant to that approach.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're actually suggesting? 
I was thinking of giving the user a text box to search for dataItemIDs and then providing a list of accepted IDs, and having the user select one of these from something like a drop down menu, and then doing the xpath query part with a hard coded string associated with that option which surely would isolate the user input from the final query?

Comment: Unfortunately in .NET the API for compiling XPath expression containing variables and then supplying values for the variables is pretty convoluted, but it is explained for example here: https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/CSHARP/XPath+injection

Comment: I couldn't seem to get the $userInput notation to play ball. Is this acceptable? 


string queryTemplate = "//*[@dataItemId = '{0}']";
query = string.Format(queryTemplate, userInput);
XPathExpression userQuery = XPathExpression.Compile(query);

Comment: @GigaJoules That's just a different way of doing string concatenation, it doesn't address the fundamentals at all.

Comment: Whenever I try to use the $userInput syntax I literally get  //*[dataItemId = '$userInput']" as my query text, not the typed search value itself? :S

Comment: It's not as if the user is able to write anything to the database right?